# SSH Key issue - Fedora 38

Tags: ssh, login, sshd, remote

I've a remote server with at least 2 users (root and myself).
I've the same keys in .ssh/authorized_keys in both $HOME folder.
I can connect with the root account, but from my account i've a "`Server refused our key`" error.
I've checked the sshd_config (on server) & the .ssh folder to check for error.
As i'm using for both account the same key ed25519 i've no clue.
the only thing I can see is `UsePAM yes` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-redhat.conf but if I remove it i'm not able to login  with passwd.

Here is the ssh -v result

```
[stan@DEL-3KC0G63 ~]$ ssh -v -i /mnt/c/Users/s.garret
/.ssh/id_ed25519 stan@192.168.1.28
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.28 [192.168.1.28] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /mnt/c/Users/s.garret/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /mnt/c/Users/s.garret/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.28:22 as 'stan'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:LjRh07mgxeC37wDufL2WmbYVYTY0tKHptZSSZGc1Q3U
debug1: Host '192.168.1.28' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/stan/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /mnt/c/Users/s.garret/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:DF1VjlJzo51HzV0TQgCcKnRCZXlhr9rCwiJuZBZzVZU explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available: Invalid UID in persistent keyring name


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available: Invalid UID in persistent keyring name


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /mnt/c/Users/s.garret/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:DF1VjlJzo51HzV0TQgCcKnRCZXlhr9rCwiJuZBZzVZU explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
stan@192.168.1.28's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
```

And the result of ls -la on the ssh folder :

```
[stan@metal ~]$ ls -la .ssh/
total 24
drwx------.  2 stan stan 4096 17 juil. 18:20 .
drwxrwxr-x. 53 stan stan 4096 17 juil. 18:38 ..
-rw-------.  1 stan stan  115  4 juil. 08:34 authorized_keys
-rw-------.  1 stan stan 2622 16 févr.  2020 id_rsa
-rw-------.  1 stan stan  582 16 févr.  2020 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------.  1 stan stan 1361 16 mai   18:33 known_hosts
[stan@metal ~]$
```

Comment: What does the sshd log say? What are the file permissions for the user `authorized_keys` file and its parent directory?

Comment: What does `ssh -v ...` tell you? Adding one or more `-v` options to your `seh` command increases verbosity.

Comment: Check the rights. You are the owner of the $HOME/authorized_keys and just you have r/w rights on that file? `ls -la $HOME/.ssh'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH does some security restrictions for your own security. While everything under ~/.ssh seems ok, stan $HOME is too open at 775/rwxrwxr-x per your .. at your .ssh directory `ls` output.

If logged as stan run:

```
chmod 700 $HOME
```

Or if root:

```
chmod 700 ~stan
```

Now your ssh ought to work.